# What are valid values for rspec :type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In an `rspec` test, it is possible to specify the type of the test e.g.

```
it 'should behave', type: :system do
   ...
end
```

What are the valid values of :type, if so, where is it documented.

Comment: For those voting to close this, the place that this information is found in the Relish documentation, is under 'Directory', which once you understand it is obvious, but hardly likely to come up in a google search looking for valid values for rspec :type

Comment: As well, there are custom types, so this question is useful for someone trying to work out if a particular spec type is custom or standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Relish documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure)

```
- Model specs: type: `:model`
- Controller specs: type: `:controller`
- Request specs: type: `:request`
- Feature specs: type: `:feature`
- View specs: type: `:view`
- Helper specs: type: `:helper`
- Mailer specs: type: `:mailer`
- Routing specs: type: `:routing`
- Job specs: type: `:job`
- System specs: type: `:system`
```

Also, as commented by arieljuod, you can have [custom spec types](http://typefast.blog/custom-spec-types-with-rspec)

Comment: Just for completeness, those are the default, but it can be anything defining custom types https://typefast.blog/custom-spec-types-with-rspec/